# How to add pop up to this flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is the code that i have used...

```
<section id="dg-container" class="dg-container">
                <div class="dg-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="js__p_start"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image01"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image02"></a>
<section>




<div class="p_body js__p_body js__fadeout"></div>
<div class="popup js__popup js__slide_top"> <a href="#" class="p_close js__p_close" title="Close"></a>
<div class="p_content">jQueryScript.Net Demo<br>
<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-for-Popup-Window.html">Download This Plugin</a></div>
</div>
```

bt could'nt combine the both....
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have followed the instructions [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-for-Popup-Window.html). Have you called the CSS and the JS files of the plugin? After that are you calling plugin like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".js__p_start").simplePopup();
    });
</script>
```

Please create a JSfiddle or a Codepen of your code and link it. Its a bit difficult to understand what you're looking for. Please explain what happens when you click the image.